# How should I set the arguments and parameters in createAsyncThunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Sometimes when I run loadPosts dispatch, I don't send any data, sometimes I send lastId data to same loadPosts disaptch.

At this time, I don't know how to define the type of data in createAsyncThunk .
When I run my code I get a red warning in loadPosts.

like this Screenshot

[image]

it says
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

How can i fix my code?

this is my code

```
    dispatch(loadPosts());


    dispatch(loadPosts(lastId:lastId));



    export const loadPosts = createAsyncThunk(
      'post/loadPosts',
      async (data: any, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(`/post?lastId=${data?.lastId || 0}`);
          return response.data;
        } catch (error: any) {
          return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTK Docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk

```
export const loadPosts = createAsyncThunk<
  YourReturnType,
  {
    lastId: number;
  } | void,
  { state: AppStore }
>('post/loadPosts', async (data, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`/post?lastId=${data?.lastId || 0}`);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the state: Appstore for?

Comment: `type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;` https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types

Answer (score 0):

Make the `data` argument optional:

```
async (data: any?, thunkAPI) => {
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @user15322469 try add question mark after "data" word `async (data?: any, thunkAPI) => {`

Comment: It doesn't work... @VasylNahuliak

Comment: @user15322469 ok, I created a separate answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72079097/10617148